# iOS Link Binary with library for debug only

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a bit of a problem with setting different configuration for my project. I have two versions of the same static library. One has logging enabled, the other doesn't.

I am using two different xcconfig files for Debug vs. Release. In these files I specify the library and header search paths for the two variants of the static lib. So far so good.

However, in my build settings I can't see a way to conditionally link the actual library. I.e use the debug variant for Debug and the release for Release.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think the quickest answer here is: you can't. But I think the solution might be providing a method to enable or disable the logs within the static lib itself. Then, you could use the same lib, just enabling or disabling the logs whenever you need to do so

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to link the library using the "Other Linker Flags" build setting, rather than the standard "Link Binary With Libraries" UI. The build setting can be changed depending on the configuration:

[image]

Click the triangle and you can give different values for Debug/Release. You will need to use the `-l` flag. For example, for a filename of `libMyLib.a` use the flag `-lMyLib`. You may need to edit the "Library Search Paths" to search the appropriate location.

If the filenames for the debug and release version are the same and you don't want to change them, put them into their own `lib/Debug` and `lib/Release` directories respectively. Then edit the "Library Search Paths" build setting adding either `"$SRCROOT/lib/Debug"` or `"$SRCROOT/lib/Release"` for the appropriate configuration.

Comment: To expand on Mike's answer, if what you want to link against is a framework you can use something like "-framework SystemConfiguration" in your Other Linker Flags

Comment: This works for me only partially. I'd like to use a shared library (*.dylib). Normally I have and entry for it in Build Phases -> Embed Frameworks in order to place the lib in the bundle. How can I choose the right lib version here?

Comment: @wroluk Did you find some solution for it ?

Comment: @jgm Most probably not. At least I do not remember (6 years passed).