# Xcode : Which library (DEBUG or RELEASE) is consumed?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, static-libraries, release

I have two `libraries i.e. DEBUG and RELEASE`. I want to know which *static library is getting called when app is build i.e. DEBUG or RELEASE*. The  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063100/xcode-ios-how-to-determine-whether-code-is-running-in-debug-release-build) determines which mode app is getting executed (DEBUG or RELEASE) but not for library.

How can this be determined in Xcode 6.4?

Comment: @Vizllx : I want to know which static library is getting called when app is build. The above link determines which mode app is getting executed (DEBUG or RELEASE) but not for library.

Comment: Now the question look promising! You must have mentioned it in first spot.

Comment: @JayprakashDubey We, normally use universal library, not specific.. You should be looking for how to create static Universal library from release and debug static libraries. Here is [link](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=create%20universal%20static%20library%20using%20release%20and%20debug%20library) that will help.

Comment: @JayprakashDubey- Yes, that is possible to do . You must have to search well to find it.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/13585189/2714702

Comment: @iphonic and Vizllx : Thanks for that link but that doesn't answer my question in any manner. I want to know code that can determine whether DEBUG or RELEASE library is executed.

Comment: @JayprakashDubey There is no programmatic way to do this for sure. But we have XCode settings where you can add specific static libraries for Device and Simulator separately.. See [this](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/xcode/how-to-add-multiple-static-library-files-with-different-architectures-to-xcode) and [this](http://www.raizlabs.com/dev/2014/03/specifying-the-build-configuration-for-xcode-project-dependencies/).

Comment: Is this library pre-built or built as a sub-project of the Xcode project?

Answer (score 1):

While creating Libraries it self we will get two different .a files for both debug and release there we have to name it properly.

Please read through [this link](http://jaym2503.blogspot.in/2013/01/how-to-make-universal-static-library.html), there you have clear description.

Comment: Your blog states how to create universal static library. I have already library in place (developed by third party). I have a scenario where I want to know whether app is build for debug or release mode programmatically.