# Including certain Objective-C files based on scheme in Swift project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I am using [SimulatorStatusMagic](https://github.com/shinydevelopment/SimulatorStatusMagic) to change the status bar within the simulator when [automating my screenshots](https://github.com/KrauseFx/snapshot). I cannot include this within non-screenshot builds due to the code not working on devices and using private APIs, restricting a submission to the app store. The project files are included directly in the project, without the use of a framework, due to the app targeting iOS 7.

Within the Objective-C Bridging Header I have:

```
#ifdef SNAPSHOT
#import "SDStatusBarManager.h"
#endif
```

I then have a separate release name "snapshot", which has the follow values:

```
Preprocessor Macros: SNAPSHOT=1
Other Swift Flags: -D SNAPSHOT
```

Within my app delegate I then have:

```
#if SNAPSHOT
SDStatusBarManager.sharedInstance().enableOverrides()
#endif
```

I (incorrectly) thought that this would allow me to submit to the app store since the code would not be compiled but I was wrong. Is there a way to only have this code included in snapshot builds?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that, even though you are only calling the library when building with the 'SNAPSHOT' flag, the library binaries are still being linked with the app, and thus being rejected by Apple.

SimulatorStatusMagic's readme says you should add it to the project only when on Debug mode to avoid that, and your Podfile settings should also reflect that.

`pod 'SimulatorStatusMagic', :configurations => ['Debug']`

Reference: https://github.com/shinydevelopment/SimulatorStatusMagic#i-have-a-script-to-take-my-screenshots-can-i-automate-this

Comment: I'm not using CocoaPods or Carthage because the app targets iOS 7.0. I should have specified this in the question!

Comment: Oops! Sorry, Joseph. The reason is probably the same, though, you just have to figure out how not to link SimulatorStatusMagic when building on Release. You could add `#ifdef DEBUG` on the source files of SimulatorStatusMagic, for example. Try that and tell me if it works, I'll fix my answer :)

Comment: I'm sure that would work, but I'd like to avoid modifying the project's files since the project is added a git submodule, and if I did make changes then any future updates wouldn't be applied without manually overriding my changes and then adding the `#ifdef SNAPSHOT`. If there's no other solution then I will accept this as the answer.

Comment: @JosephDuffy, how are you building/linking to SimulatorStatusMagic? check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13585189/2752598). Try setting it to link or to include the source files only on a specific configuration.